# Equations to create this Graph Picture

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I'm using a online graphing tool "Desmos" to create the image bellow (sunset).
[image: sunset]

I created the 3 circles to form the sun. Using these equations:
[image]
However, I am stuck on creating the images for the other lines.. The curve ones specifically. How should I go about creating the equations for those lines. Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is how I would attempt this**

Ok first for simplicity lets call:

the line made by joining points $(-17,0)$ and $(-3,9)$ as Line **A**

and the line made by joining points $(-12,0)$ and $(-3,9)$ as Line **B**

and the left curve and right curve as shown in the diagram.

---

Now to find the line of A and B is pretty simple, Il do for one (Line A) to demonstrate it.

The equation of a striaght line is $y=mx+c$

where m is the gradient and c is the intercept.

$m=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}$

where in Line *A* the values are :

$x_1=-17$

$x_2=-3$

$y_1=0$

$y_2=9$

Now plugin these and then to now since you know the value of m, to find c

you have

$y=mx+c$

$c=y-mx$

Put any co ordinate out of the two. Il put $(-3,9)$

and you get

$c=9-m(-3)$

Because you know m you can find c, and this is the equation of line A. Follow the method for line B.

---

Now for the curves, lets first look at curve on the right side

We know three points on the curve which are $(-27,17)$ , $(-9,3)$ and $(-3,9)$

and we know its in the form $y=a+c log_b(dx)$

But there are 4 unkowns you need to solve for a,b,c,d. So that means you need 4 equations. So the first three equations will be subsituting the 3 points that they have given into the equation. Which gives:

$17=a+c log_b(-27d)$

$3=a+c log_b(-9d)$

$9=a+c log_b(-3d)$

And in order to get the 4th equation you should know that, the line **A** is normal to the point (-3,9) on the curve, this means that you need to differentiate the function $y=a+c log_b(dx)$ and then you get the first derivative which is a function. 
Then to this when you substitute x=-3 to this function ($dy/dx$) you get an expression with a bunch of unknowns. Lets call this expression as T. NOW we want a formula (not an expression) so we should know that the gradient of line A (which you should know by now) multiplied by the T is equal to -1. (This is a rule)

So there you have it a 4th equation, now you can solve the 4 equations, find the four unknowns and plot this curve.

---

Now the curve at the Right side , it **approximately** looks like the mirror image of the curve on the left side at a vertical line (which I will tell in a moment) and they have mentioned a point it meets, so I would say the right hand side is the reflection of the curve on the left side about the line $x=-9$ (the line of reflection). Look closely, or better yet draw the line $x=-9$ and this will become clear to you.

So since you know its the reflection of the left curve (a known curve by now) and you know a point it meets, and you know the line of reflection. I dont think it would be hard to proceed from this point on. Try these, if you get stuck ;) Dont forget to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You have an equation for the left curve: $f(x)=a+c\log_b(dx)$. This curve has to pass through three points: $(-27,17),(-9,13)$ and $(-3,9)$. That means that for each point $P$ of coordinates $(x_P,y_P)$ you must have $f(x_P)=y_P$. Try to find the coefficients $a,b,c$ and $d$ letting the logarithm pass through the three points.